Locating expired certificates in certsrv
I have a Windows Server  2016 CA I am attempting to get the CA working again. (i'm not very experienced in Windows Server, so I've been working it out as I go).
When looking at the certsrv properties, I can see the newly created root certificates that I made and can see them in the certificate stores (Local Computer\Trusted Root, CertSvc\Trusted Root, NTDS\Trusted Root), but am unable to find the expired one at all. Where would I be able to locate that one?

I've noticed when viewing the expired certificate, the CA version in the properties is v0.0 which seems a bit odd..
